# invokeLater's run() method being called twice

Tags: blackberry

In order to determine which screen to display next in my BlackBerry app I'm using the code below. For some strange reason, however, the code within `run()` gets executed twice when a menu item is selected by tapping onscreen yet only once when using the phone's keypad instead.

Any ideas what might be causing this?

```java
protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time)
{
    switch (mainMenu.getSelectedIndex())
    {
    case 0:
        UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run() 
            {
                UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new PollListScreen());
            }
        });
        break;
    case 1:
        UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run() 
            {
                UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new UpdateProfileScreen());
            }
        });
        break;

        // Etc.

    default:
        break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: As an aside, using `invokeAndWait()` instead doesn't cause this problem

Comment: In which type of class are you overriding this `navigationClick()` method?  A subclass of *what*?

Answer (score 1):

I can't see exactly **where** you've placed the code that you're showing, but I don't think too many things can be going wrong here.

If `run()` is being called multiple times, then I think `navigationClick()` is getting called multiple times.

`navigationClick()` can get called differently depending on the source of the *click* (e.g. touch vs. trackwheel).  You should, however, be able to sort this out by inspecting the `status` parameter.  Something like this might do for you:

```java
protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time)
{
    if (status != 0)  // <-- NOTICE THIS CHECK!!!
    {
        switch (mainMenu.getSelectedIndex())
        {
            case 0:
            // your code cut out here for clarity
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

If you use `invokeAndWait()`, you're probably blocking the UI thread, which might cause problems for the second invocation of `navigationClick()`.  That would be using *two wrongs to make a right*, though.  `invokeLater()` should usually be preferred.

Comment: Spot on Nate! `navigationClick()` is being called twice for some reason, I can't seem to figure out why though. This only happens with touch events, clicks from the scroll-wheel only call `navigationCLick()` once. Any ideas?

Comment: @Bataleon, as i mentioned, inspect the value of the "status" param passed. it should be different for the two separate invocations, allowing you to filter out one. see the [javadoc for navigationClick() for more](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Field.html#navigationClick%28int,%20int%29)

Comment: The value of the "status" param is 0 for both invocations. Strangely `nacigationClick()` is called twice only in the simulator. On real hardware (BlackBerry Torch) everything operates as expected.

Comment: @Bataleon, I'm not on my Windows machine right now (thus, no simulator).  You're sure it's not just that on the simulator, you have a mouse, and you're double-clicking the mouse?  Just want to rule that out ...

Comment: Yes, I'm single clicking with the mouse. Funnily enough when I add a `touchEvent(TouchEvent message)` method which does nothing but call `message.getEvent()` and then return false, the problem disappears! (On both the simulator and handset.)

Comment: @Bataleon, you didn't answer my original question about what kind of class you're overriding `navigationClick()` inside.  But, just for reference, the code I use to create custom ButtonFields, overrides `navigationClick()` and implements `touchEvent()`, and I never have this problem (double invocation, on simulator).  So, maybe that's the key.  Again, the semantics of these calls are changed for touch events vs. trackwheel events, so I guess this doesn't surprise me.